# libcld.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory error when using CLD

Tags: 12.04, python-2.7, shared-library

I am getting this error while trying to use CLD:

```
libcld.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

`libcld` is not a part of Ubuntu, but something the author of CLD wrote.

As he says in [CLD's readme](https://github.com/mzsanford/cld/blob/master/README.md), you will have to compile and install that library yourself from the source provided in his [github repository](https://github.com/mzsanford/cld).